# how can I make a control for my vector equation in my simulation?

Tags: vector, gui-construction, simulation

I'm trying to build a control selector or menu for equations to put into my curvature simulations. However all the code I've tried hasn't worked.Does anyone know how I could make a control selector or menu for a position vector r[t] in my simulation?

```
r[t_] := {3 Cos[t], Sin[t]}
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
x[t_] := r[t][[1]]
y[t_] := r[t][[2]]

y2[t_] = r[t] + ((1/(uT[t]/r'[t])) vN[t])

OlcusionPoint[t_] := y2[t][[1]]
(*-((((x'[t])^2+(y'[t])^2)*y'[t])/((x'[t]*y''[t])-(x''[t]*y'[t])))*)
OclusionPoint2[t_] := y2[t][[2]]

(*+((((x'[t])^2+(y'[t])^2)*x'[t])/((x'[t]*y''[t])-(x''[t]*y'[t])))*)
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], 
    Disk[{OlcusionPoint[t], OclusionPoint2[t]}, 
     Abs[1/(uT[t]/r'[t])]]}], 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[{x[t], y[t]}]}]], {t, 0.0001, 
  2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Neither `Selector` nor `Menu` are type of controllers in Mathematica. So what do you want and what do you want it to do? Take a look at [ref/ControlObjects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ControlObjects.html)

Comment: I was think either an Action or Popup menu

Comment: Is this: `Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], 
    Disk[{OlcusionPoint[t], OclusionPoint2[t]}, 
     Abs[1/(uT[t]/r'[t])]]}], 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[{x[t], y[t]}]}]],
 {t, 0.0001, 2 Pi},
 Row[{ActionMenu["Pos", 
    Rest@Most@Table[With[{t1 = t1}, r[t1] :> (t = t1)], {t1, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/9}]]}]
 ]` what you need?

Comment: Or:fun = "{x[t],y[t]}";
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8],
    Disk[{OlcusionPoint[t], OclusionPoint2[t]}, 
     Abs[1/(uT[t]/r'[t])]]}],
  ParametricPlot[ToExpression@fun, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[{x[t], y[t]}]}], 
  ImageSize -> {500, 500}],
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic@t, {0.0001, 2 Pi}],
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@fun, {"{x[t],y[t]}", "{2*x[t],y[t]}"}, 
    FieldSize -> {10, 1}]
   }],
 TrackedSymbols -> {t, fun}
 ]

Answer (score 3):

#### Edited

I don't like this much because what I take are intended to be the osculating circles don't have a radius equal to the radius of curvature. I used your formula, but it appears to be wrong.

Nevertheless, what I've worked out does install a popup menu into a `Manipulate` expression which will select which parametric function will be displayed. It will work with any reasonable number of parametric forms.

```
Clear[t]; forms = {{3 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}};
lbls = ToString /@ forms;
indxs = Range[Length[forms]];
rules = Thread[Rule[indxs, lbls]];
(r[t_, #] = forms[[#]]) & /@ indxs;
(dr[t_, #] = D[r[t, #], t]) & /@ indxs;
(uT[t_, #] = Simplify[dr[t, #]/Norm[dr[t, #]], t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(vN[t_, #] = Simplify[With[{du = D[uT[t, #], t]}, du/Norm[du]], t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(center[t_, #] = r[t, #] + ((1/(uT[t, #]/dr[t, #])) vN[t, #])) & /@ indxs;
(radius[t_, #] = Abs[1/(uT[t, #]/dr[t, #])]) & /@ indxs;

Manipulate[Show[
  Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], Disk[center[t, k], radius[t, k]]}],
  ParametricPlot[r[t, k], {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[r[t, k]]}]],
  {{k, 1, "function"}, rules, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
  {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

This shows the `Manipulate` with your parametric function selected

[image: func-1]

and this shows it with the other functions selected

[image: func-2]

#### update

I've redone this demonstration using correct functions for the center and radius of curvature. It looks much better.

```
Clear[t]; forms = {{3 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}};
lbls = ToString /@ forms;
indxs = Range[Length[forms]];
rules = Thread[Rule[indxs, lbls]];
(r[t_, #] = forms[[#]]) & /@ indxs;
(dr[t_, #] = D[r[t, #], t]) & /@ indxs;
(d2r[t_, #] = D[r[t, #], {t, 2}]) & /@ indxs;
(uT[t_, #] = Simplify[dr[t, #]/Norm[dr[t, #]], t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(vN[t_, #] = Simplify[With[{du = D[uT[t, #], t]}, du/Norm[du]], t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(radius[t_, #] = 
  Simplify[
    Norm[dr[t, #]]^3 /
      Abs[dr[t, #][[1]] d2r[t, #][[2]] - dr[t, #][[2]] d2r[t, #][[1]]],
    t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
(center[t_, #] = Simplify[r[t, #] + radius[t, #] vN[t, #], t ∈ Reals]) & /@ indxs;
```

The `Manipulate` expression remains the same. With the new definitions for `radius` and `center`, the osculating circles are drawn correctly.

[image: func-3]

[image: func-4]

Comment: Bravo! Radius is now lowest at point of highest curvature which is much more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could add labels in the menu like Eclipse,Lemniscate?

Comment: @user14520. Yes I could do that, but do you want to substitute the names for the curve forms, or do you want them as an addition to the curve forms? BTW, Eclipse and Lemniscate are not correct names for the curves I used in the above code. I really feel labeling with the forms gives the most informative labeling.

Comment: @user14520 - please see my new answer below which add labels to the menu

Comment: m_goldberg the simulation runs very nisley on Mathematica but when I run it on cdf preview there is an error. like center[0,1] should be a pair of numbers or scaledOffset form.

Comment: @user14520. I know almost nothing about CDF. It may be that you need to add one or more options to your `Manipulate`. It may be that it can't run in the CDF player, which places restrictions on the _Mathematica_ code that can run there. Best to ask for help on this new problem in a new question.

Comment: @user14520. If you are going to be a frequent participant in this site, it also be a good idea for you to become a registered member.

Answer (score 1):

`Manipulate` can be tricky, and it's sometimes hard to answer questions without simply doing a full implementation for the OP.  In this case, it is possible to adapt the OP's initial structure, but there are several issues that makes a simple fix elusive.  They are primarily related to the scope of symbols.

(The side issue of an incorrect formula for curvature has been pointed out by [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066).  That will be left to the OP.)

#### The control

Before we get to the issues, let me first present the way I might create the control.  I will deal with the issues later.  First make the list of functions you want to use.  This can be done is two steps:  Make a list of expressions and convert them to functions.  The list of expressions is easy to maintain.

```
Clear[t];
fns = {{3 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[3 t], Sin[t]}, {t, Cos[t]}};
fns = Function @@@ Thread[{t, fns}];
```

The control can be inserted into the `Manipulate` with the code

```
{{r, First[fns]}, # -> #[t] & /@ fns, PopupMenu},
```

#### The issues

First, in a global definition like this

```
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
```

the symbol `r` is a variable in the `` Global` `` context `` Global`r ``.  But in `Manipulate`, by default, `r` will have a context that is local to the cell in which the `Manipulate` output appears.

Second, the definition

```
y2[t_] = r[t] + ((1/(uT[t]/r'[t])) vN[t])
```

which uses `Set`, will use the current definition of `r`.  If `r` is not yet defined, then `uT` will be evaluated and the definition ends up with `Norm'[r'[t]]` in it, and `Norm'` is undefined.

Third, another issue has to do with the symbol `t` as a symbolic variable in a function expression and as a numeric value of the parameter to be substituted for the symbolic variable.  Care has to be taken to keep the two uses from clashing.

There are various ways to deal with these issues.  The simplest way to deal with the first is to use the option `LocalizeVariables -> False`.  It may not be the best way, depending on what else is going on in the user's *Mathematica* session.  The second is handles by using `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  For the third, the best thing to do is to use two different symbols, say `t` for the symbolic variable and `t0` for the numeric value.

#### One fix

```
Clear[t, r, y2];
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
x[t_] := r[t][[1]]
y[t_] := r[t][[2]]
y2[t_] := r[t] + ((1/(uT[t]/r'[t])) vN[t]);
OlcusionPoint[t_] := y2[t][[1]];
OclusionPoint2[t_] := y2[t][[2]];

fns = {{3 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[3 t], Sin[t]}, {t, Cos[t]}};
fns = Function @@@ Thread[{t, fns}];
t0 = 0.0001; (* needed if localization is false *)

Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], 
    Disk[{OlcusionPoint[t0], OclusionPoint2[t0]}, 
     Abs[1/(uT[t0]/r'[t0])]]}], 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[{x[t0], y[t0]}]}]],

 {{r, First[fns]}, # -> #[t] & /@ fns, PopupMenu},

 {{t0, 0.0001, t}, 0.0001, 2 Pi},

 LocalizeVariables -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

#### Another fix

I would localize things.  The `ControlType -> None` make the symbol be localized in the `DynamicModule` created by `Manipulate`.  The form `{{x, x}, ...}` initializes the symbol `x` to the symbol `x`; otherwise, it will be initialized to `0`, the default initialization.  This is needed for the `SetDelayed` definition of `x` in the `Initialization` option to work.

**Update**: Curvature is fixed; code is simplified.

```
Clear[t];

fns = {{3 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[3 t], Sin[t]}, {t, Cos[t]}};
fns = Function @@@ Thread[{t, fns}];

Manipulate[
 With[{curve = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]},
  Show[
   Graphics[{RGBColor[0.6, 0.6, 0.8], Disk[y2[t0], rad[t0]]}],
   curve,                  (* draw curve on top of osculating disk *)
   Graphics[{PointSize[.025], Point[r[t0]]}],
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.15], Axes -> False,
   Options[curve]]         (* Primarily to get the PlotRange *)
  ],

 {{r, First[fns]}, # -> #[t] & /@ fns, PopupMenu},

 {{t0, 0.0001, t}, 0.0001, 2 Pi},

 {{uT, uT}, ControlType -> None}, {{vN, vN}, ControlType -> None},
 {{y2, y2}, ControlType -> None}, {{rad, rad}, ControlType -> None},

 Initialization :> (
   uT[t_] := #/Norm[#] &[r'[t]] // ComplexExpand;
   vN[t_] := #/Norm[#] &[uT'[t]];
   rad[t_] := Norm[r'[t]]/Norm[uT'[t]];
   y2[t_] := r[t] + rad[t] vN[t];
   )]
```

The list of dummy controls can be generated with

```
Thread[{Transpose[{#, #}] &@{
    uT, vN, y2, rad
    }, ControlType -> None}]
```

which is a form that is relatively easy to maintain.  One could also put it directly into `Manipulate` with

```
Evaluate[
 Sequence @@ Thread[{Transpose[{#, #}] &@{
      uT, vN, y2, rad
      }, ControlType -> None}]
 ]
```

but you lose the syntax coloring.

Comment: I estimate your effort, but it's far too complicated - just plug your formulas into my code below.